# Amazon, AWS, images and Carrierwave - everything working but no upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I've been trying to get this to work for what feels like my whole life up to this point.

Got to the stage where:

React sends an image in formData.
My Company model has a company_logo uploader.
Image seems to attach successfully.
Company saves successfully.

But:
in the company_logo field, it's just the name of the file...
and there is nothing in AWS.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

```js
company.company_logo = params['companylogo']
=> #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f92ca3371b0
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers=
  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"companylogo\"; filename=\"TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @original_filename="TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/cg/4d0655v10j9_zzkkclng3ch00000gn/T/RackMultipart20181003-74913-1cgb17m.jpg>>
[4] pry(#<NewController>)> company
=> #<Company:0x00007f92cc881060
 id: nil,
 name: "sdkljfjklsdf",
 pod_id: 9,
 officelocation: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 campaign_link: nil,
 company_logo: nil>
[5] pry(#<NewController>)> company.company_logo
=> #<CompanyLogoUploader:0x00007f92c6862aa8
 @cache_id="1538555179-74913-0001-2710",
 @cache_storage=
  #<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x00007f92c6860708
   @cache_called=nil,
   @uploader=#<CompanyLogoUploader:0x00007f92c6862aa8 ...>>,
 @file=
  #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x00007f92c68619c8
   @content=nil,
   @content_type="image/jpeg",
   @file="/Users/paulharker/projects/tpdb/tmp/uploads/1538555179-74913-0001-2710/TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg",
   @original_filename="TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg">,
 @filename="TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg",
 @model=
  #<Company:0x00007f92cc881060
   id: nil,
   name: "sdkljfjklsdf",
   pod_id: 9,
   officelocation: nil,
   created_at: nil,
   updated_at: nil,
   campaign_link: nil,
   company_logo: nil>,
 @mounted_as=:company_logo,
 @original_filename="TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg",
 @versions={}>
[6] pry(#<NewController>)> company.save!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ (pry):8
  Company Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "pod_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "company_logo") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "sdkljfjklsdf"], ["pod_id", 9], ["created_at", "2018-10-03 08:26:53.929667"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-03 08:26:53.929667"], ["company_logo", "TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg"]]
  ↳ (pry):8
   (5.5ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ (pry):8
=> true
```

and my carrierwave.rb initializer...

```js
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 

  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET'],
    region: 'eu-west-2'
  }
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_directory = 'images' # bucket name


  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads" # To let CarrierWave work on heroku
end
```

Comment: what do you get when you call `company.company_logo_url`?

Comment: so, before company.save! I get `/Users/[username]/projects/tpdb/tmp/uploads/1538559653-78449-0001-6148/TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg`

Comment: and after company.save! I get `"/uploads/company/company_logo/19/TP-Twitter-Profile.jpg"` ... so I'm guessing it's not saving to AWS?

Comment: yes. it's not saving to S3/aws

Comment: in your company_logo_uploader, did you mention `storage :fog` ? because your initializer looks just fine.

Comment: any hypothesis as to why?  I've set `config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'` and `config.storage = :fog` in my initializer... does it have to be set anywhere else?

Comment: also you should try removing `config.storage = :fog` from initializer

Comment: don't think so, only in the initializer...

Comment: then that is the issue. You have to mention it in your uploader. look at this section - https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3

Comment: It's working, thank you very much...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kiddorails points out in the conversation above, you need to add `storage :fog` to the uploader, and not in the initializer.

Link for more info: 
[github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3](http://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3)